# Submenu with distance, on hover is closed

Tags: html, css, styling

I have a submenu, the problem is my submenu must have more distance and should be visible on **hover**, so if i'm out of *li* the submenu goes closed.

[image]

Demonstration code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickyr3/N23AM/).

HTML code is:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="#">submenu</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item 5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item 6</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item 7</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS is:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.menu {
}
ul.menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
}
ul.menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: #5b615b;
    padding: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.menu li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
ul.menu li ul {
    display: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
ul.menu li:hover > a {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
ul.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
ul.menu li ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
ul.menu li.active ul li a {
    color: #5b615b;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `top` on `ul.menu li ul` to `33px` instead of 37, and add a `padding-top` of `1px`. [Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/N23AM/1/).

The padding ensures that the hover effect remains active between the elements (padding is part of the element so also has hover).

Answer (score 1):

```
ul.menu li ul {
display: none;
font-size: 10px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 34px;
left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

change top:37; to top:34; If you want to maintain the whitespace, you can add a 3px white border to the bottom of the top li.

jsfiddle showing this method http://jsfiddle.net/N23AM/4/

visualy identical, just allows the hover to be maintained by the border rather than losing focusing to the background.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solutions would be to add `padding-top:20px;`(your desired value would be there of course) put in `ul li:hover ul` selector.

Another, maybe strange solution, that I could think of is to add in your `ul` submenu a new div that looks like this:

```
<div style="height:20px; background:transparent; width:100%;"></div>
```